# 418 I'm a TeapotServer for RESTful integration-tests

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, framework, integration-testing

I created a test-server for RESTful integration-tests that I call `TeapotServer` because I like the status-code `418` that the server returns when the client makes a mistake and sends it an invalid request.

#### Example

Its API is similar to `JustMock`. I first tell it to what API I want to test, how the request should look like, how many of them I expect and what response(s) it should return.

There are two types of assertions:
- as requests arrive to validate them as soon as possible
- after the request to validate whether they have been even called

```
public class HttpProviderExtensionsTest : IDisposable, IClassFixture<TeapotServerFixture>
{
    private readonly ITeapotServerContext _serverContext;

    private readonly IResourceProvider _http;

    public HttpProviderExtensionsTest(TeapotServerFixture teapotServerFixture)
    {
        _serverContext = teapotServerFixture.GetServer("http://localhost:30002").BeginScope();
        _http = HttpProvider.FromBaseUri("http://localhost:30002/api");
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Can_send_email_and_receive_html()
    {
        _serverContext
            .MockPost("/api/mailr/messages/test", request =>
            {
                request
                    .AcceptsHtml()
                    .AsUserAgent("xunit", "1.0")
                    .WithContentTypeJson(content =>
                    {
                        content
                            .HasProperty("$.To")
                            .HasProperty("$.Subject")
                            //.HasProperty("$.From") // Boom! This property does not exist.
                            .HasProperty("$.Body.Greeting");
                    })
                    .Occurs(1); // <-- short-circuit on 2nd request
            })
            .ArrangeResponse(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .Once(200, "OK!");
            });

        var email = new Email.Html(new[] { "myemail@mail.com" }, "Test-mail")
        {
            Body = new { Greeting = "Hallo Mailr!" }
        };

        var response = await _http.SendEmailAsync("mailr/messages/test", new UserAgent("xunit", "1.0"), email);

        _serverContext.Assert();
        Assert.Equal("OK!", response);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serverContext.Dispose();
        _http.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### Server + Middleware

The `TeapotServer` is based on `Kestrel` and uses a single `TeapotMiddleware`. I use it to forward requests to assertions that can short-circuit the pipeline (unlike [`Flurl`](https://flurl.dev) that I don't like because of its assertions that take place too late - they cannot protect you from infinite request loops).

```
[PublicAPI]
public class TeapotServer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWebHost _host;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ITeapotServerContext> _serverContexts = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ITeapotServerContext>();

    public TeapotServer(string url)
    {
        var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                // Tests can use their own urls so let's not use hosting.json but in-memory-collection
                .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["urls"] = url // <-- this is the only way that works with Kestrel
                })
                .Build();

        _host =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    // Allows to validate requests as they arrive.
                    services.AddSingleton((RequestAssertDelegate)Assert);
                    // Allows to provide custom responses for each request.
                    services.AddSingleton((ResponseMockDelegate)GetResponseFactory);
                })
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseMiddleware<TeapotMiddleware>();
                })
                .Build();

        _host.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // <-- asp.net-core TestServer is doing this too.
    }

    //public Task Task { get; set; } // <-- I think I don't need this anymore...

    // Creates a new server-context that separates api-mocks.
    public ITeapotServerContext BeginScope()
    {
        return _serverContexts.GetOrAdd(Guid.NewGuid(), id => new TeapotServerContext(Disposable.Create(() => _serverContexts.TryRemove(id, out _))));
    }

    private void Assert(RequestCopy requestCopy)
    {
        FindApiMock(requestCopy.Method, requestCopy.Uri)?.Assert(requestCopy);
    }

    private Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> GetResponseFactory(HttpMethod method, UriString uri)
    {
        return FindApiMock(method, uri)?.GetResponseFactory();
    }

    // Finds an api-mock that should handle the current request.
    [CanBeNull]
    private ApiMock FindApiMock(HttpMethod method, UriString uri)
    {
        if (_serverContexts.IsEmpty) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot get response without a server-context. Call '{nameof(BeginScope)}' first.");

        var mocks =
            from tc in _serverContexts.Values
            from rm in tc
            where rm.Method == method && rm.Uri == uri
            select rm;

        return mocks.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _host.StopAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _host.Dispose();
    }
}

public delegate void RequestAssertDelegate(RequestCopy requestCopy);

[CanBeNull]
public delegate Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> ResponseMockDelegate(HttpMethod method, UriString path);

[UsedImplicitly]
internal class TeapotMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly RequestAssertDelegate _requestAssert;
    private readonly ResponseMockDelegate _nextResponseMock;

    public TeapotMiddleware
    (
        RequestDelegate next,
        RequestAssertDelegate requestAssert,
        ResponseMockDelegate nextResponseMock
    )
    {
        _next = next;
        _requestAssert = requestAssert;
        _nextResponseMock = nextResponseMock;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString;

            // You need this later to restore the body so don't dispose it.
            var bodyBackup = new MemoryStream();

            // You copy it because the original stream does not support seeking.
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(bodyBackup);

            // You copy the request because otherwise it won't pass the "barrier" between the middleware and the assert.
            using (var bodyCopy = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await bodyBackup.Rewind().CopyToAsync(bodyCopy);

                var request = new RequestCopy
                {
                    Uri = uri,
                    Method = new HttpMethod(context.Request.Method),
                    // There is no copy-constructor.
                    Headers = new HeaderDictionary(context.Request.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)),
                    ContentLength = context.Request.ContentLength,
                    Content = bodyCopy
                };

                _requestAssert(request);
            }

            // Restore body.
            context.Request.Body = bodyBackup;

            await _next(context);

            var responseMock = _nextResponseMock(new HttpMethod(context.Request.Method), uri);
            if (responseMock is null)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            }
            else
            {
                using (var response = responseMock(context.Request))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;

                    // Let's see what kind of content we got and handle it appropriately...

                    if (response.ContentType == MimeType.Plain)
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync((string)response.Content);
                    }

                    if (response.ContentType == MimeType.Binary)
                    {
                        await ((Stream)response.Content).Rewind().CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
                    }

                    if (response.ContentType == MimeType.Json)
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // It looks like the client sent an invalid request.
            if (ex is DynamicException dex && dex.NameMatches("AssertException"))
            {
                // "Response status code does not indicate success: 418 (I'm a teapot)."
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status418ImATeapot; // <-- I find this one funny. 
            }
            // Nope, there is a problem with the server.
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = MimeType.Plain;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.ToString()); // <-- dump the exception to the response stream.
        }
    }
}
```

#### Helpers

There is a hole bunch of helpers that provide (hopefully) a user-friendly API.

---

They start with the `TeapotServerContext` that separates api-mocks between test methods. I created a couple of convenience shortcut extensions like `MockGet` to save typing. Each of those returns an `ApiMock` that stores a pair of request and response builders for a single `API`. They are used to configure request asserts and responses.

```
public interface ITeapotServerContext : IEnumerable<ApiMock>, IDisposable
{
    ApiMock MockApi(HttpMethod method, UriString uri);

    void Assert();
}

internal class TeapotServerContext : List<ApiMock>, ITeapotServerContext
{
    private readonly IDisposable _disposer;

    public TeapotServerContext(IDisposable disposer)
    {
        _disposer = disposer;
    }

    public ApiMock MockApi(HttpMethod method, UriString uri)
    {
        var mock = new ApiMock(method, uri);
        Add(mock);
        return mock;
    }

    public void Assert()
    {
        foreach (var apiMock in this)
        {
            apiMock.Assert();
        }
    }

    public Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> GetResponseFactory(HttpMethod method, UriString uri)
    {
        return this.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Method == method && m.Uri == uri)?.GetResponseFactory();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposer.Dispose();
    }
}

public static class TeapotServerContextExtensions
{
    public static ApiMock MockGet(this ITeapotServerContext context, string uri, Action<IRequestBuilder> configureRequest)
    {
        return
            context
                .MockApi(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
                .ArrangeRequest(configureRequest);
    }

    public static ApiMock MockPost(this ITeapotServerContext context, string uri, Action<IRequestBuilder> configureRequest)
    {
        return
            context
                .MockApi(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
                .ArrangeRequest(configureRequest);
    }

    public static ApiMock MockPut(this ITeapotServerContext context, string uri, Action<IRequestBuilder> configureRequest)
    {
        return
            context
                .MockApi(HttpMethod.Put, uri)
                .ArrangeRequest(configureRequest);
    }

    public static ApiMock MockDelete(this ITeapotServerContext context, string uri, Action<IRequestBuilder> configureRequest)
    {
        return
            context
                .MockApi(HttpMethod.Delete, uri)
                .ArrangeRequest(configureRequest);
    }
}

// Represents a single api-mock.
public class ApiMock
{
    private readonly IRequestBuilder _request;
    private readonly IResponseBuilder _response;

    public ApiMock(HttpMethod method, UriString uri)
    {
        Method = method;
        Uri = uri;

        _request = new RequestBuilder();
        _response = new ResponseBuilder().Always(200, new { Message = "OK" }, MimeType.Json);
    }

    public HttpMethod Method { get; }

    public UriString Uri { get; }

    // Allows to configure request asserts.
    public ApiMock ArrangeRequest(Action<IRequestBuilder> configure)
    {
        configure(_request);
        return this;
    }

    // Allows to configure responses.
    public ApiMock ArrangeResponse(Action<IResponseBuilder> configure)
    {
        configure(_response.Clear());
        return this;
    }

    // Validates the request either as it arrives (not-null) or afterwards (null).
    public void Assert(RequestCopy requestCopy = default)
    {
        try
        {
            _request.Assert(requestCopy);
        }
        catch (Exception inner)
        {
            throw DynamicException.Create("Assert", $"{Method} {Uri}", inner);
        }
    }

    // Tries to get the nest response.
    public Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> GetResponseFactory()
    {
        return request => _response?.Next(request);
    }
}
```

#### Request and response builders

- The `RequestBuilder` keeps a collection of assert `Action`s and calls each of them when a request arrives. Assertions are created with convenience extensions that can validate headers, content etc.
- The `ResponseBuilder` keeps a collection of response factories. It's a queue where each item can produce either a response or `null` in which case it's removed from the queue an the next factory is used. When there are no more response factories an exception is thrown.

```
public interface IRequestBuilder
{
    [NotNull]
    IRequestBuilder Add(Action<RequestCopy> assert, bool canShortCircuit);

    void Assert(RequestCopy requestCopy);
}

// Maintains a collection of request-asserts.
internal class RequestBuilder : IRequestBuilder
{
    private readonly IList<(Action<RequestCopy> Assert, bool CanShortCircuit)> _asserts = new List<(Action<RequestCopy>, bool CanShortCircuit)>();

    // Adds a request assert. If it can-short-circuit then it can validate requests as they arrive.
    public IRequestBuilder Add(Action<RequestCopy> assert, bool canShortCircuit)
    {
        _asserts.Add((assert, canShortCircuit));
        return this;
    }

    // Fires all asserts.
    public void Assert(RequestCopy requestCopy)
    {
        foreach (var (assert, canShortCircuit) in _asserts)
        {
            if (requestCopy is null && !canShortCircuit)
            {
                continue;
            }

            assert(requestCopy);
        }
    }
}

[PublicAPI]
public static class RequestBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IRequestBuilder Occurs(this IRequestBuilder builder, int exactly)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        return builder.Add(request =>
        {
            if (request.CanShortCircuit())
            {
                if (++counter > exactly)
                {
                    throw DynamicException.Create(nameof(Occurs), $"Api was called {counter} time(s) but expected {exactly}.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (counter != exactly)
                {
                    throw DynamicException.Create(nameof(Occurs), $"Api was called {counter} time(s) but expected {exactly}.");
                }
            }
        }, true);
    }

    public static IRequestBuilder WithHeader(this IRequestBuilder builder, string header, params string[] expectedValues)
    {
        return builder.Add(request =>
        {
            if (request.CanShortCircuit())
            {
                if (request.Headers.TryGetValue(header, out var actualValues))
                {
                    if (actualValues.Intersect(expectedValues).Count() != expectedValues.Count())
                    {
                        throw DynamicException.Create
                        (
                            "DifferentHeader",
                            $"Expected: [{expectedValues.Join(", ")}]{Environment.NewLine}" +
                            $"Actual:   [{actualValues.Join(", ")}]"
                        );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw DynamicException.Create
                    (
                        "HeaderNotFound",
                        $"Header '{header}' is missing."
                    );
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }

    public static IRequestBuilder WithApiVersion(this IRequestBuilder builder, string version) => builder.WithHeader("Api-Version", version);

    public static IRequestBuilder WithContentType(this IRequestBuilder builder, string mediaType) => builder.WithHeader("Content-Type", mediaType);

    public static IRequestBuilder WithContentTypeJson(this IRequestBuilder builder, Action<ContentSection<JToken>> contentAssert)
    {
        return builder.Add(request =>
        {
            var content = request.DeserializeAsJToken();
            contentAssert(ContentSection.FromJToken(content));
        }, false);
    }

    public static IRequestBuilder AsUserAgent(this IRequestBuilder builder, string product, string version) => builder.WithHeader("User-Agent", $"{product}/{version}");

    public static IRequestBuilder Accepts(this IRequestBuilder builder, string mediaType) => builder.WithHeader("Accept", mediaType);

    public static IRequestBuilder AcceptsJson(this IRequestBuilder builder) => builder.Accepts("application/json");

    public static IRequestBuilder AcceptsHtml(this IRequestBuilder builder) => builder.Accepts("text/html");
}

public interface IResponseBuilder
{
    [NotNull]
    ResponseBuilder Enqueue(Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> next);

    ResponseBuilder Clear();

    [NotNull]
    ResponseMock Next(HttpRequest request);
}

public class ResponseBuilder : IResponseBuilder
{
    private readonly Queue<Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock>> _responses = new Queue<Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock>>();

    public ResponseBuilder Enqueue(Func<HttpRequest, ResponseMock> next)
    {
        _responses.Enqueue(next);
        return this;
    }

    public ResponseBuilder Clear()
    {
        _responses.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    // Gets the next response or throws when there are none.
    public ResponseMock Next(HttpRequest request)
    {
        while (_responses.Any())
        {
            var createResponse = _responses.Peek();
            var response = createResponse(request);

            // This response factory is empty.
            if (response is null)
            {
                // Remove it from the queue an try again.
                _responses.Dequeue();
                continue;
            }

            return response;
        }

        throw DynamicException.Create("OutOfResponses", "There are no more responses");
    }
}

[PublicAPI]
public static class ResponseBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IResponseBuilder Once(this IResponseBuilder response, int statusCode, object content, string contentType = default)
    {
        return response.Exactly(statusCode, content, content.DetermineContentType(contentType), 1);
    }

    public static IResponseBuilder Always(this IResponseBuilder response, int statusCode, object content, string contentType = default)
    {
        return response.Enqueue(request => new ResponseMock(statusCode, content, content.DetermineContentType(contentType)));
    }

    public static IResponseBuilder Exactly(this IResponseBuilder response, int statusCode, object content, string contentType, int count)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        return response.Enqueue(request => counter++ < count ? new ResponseMock(statusCode, content, contentType) : default);
    }

    // Forwards request to response.
    public static IResponseBuilder Echo(this IResponseBuilder response)
    {
        return response.Enqueue(request =>
        {
            var requestCopy = new MemoryStream();
            request.Body.Rewind().CopyTo(requestCopy);
            return new ResponseMock(200, requestCopy, MimeType.Binary);
        });
    }

    private static string DetermineContentType(this object content, string contentType)
    {
        return contentType ?? (content is string ? MimeType.Plain : MimeType.Json);
    }
}
```

#### Data

Other classes used here are mainly of `DTO` nature that just pass data from one place to the other.

```
public class ContentSection<TContent> where TContent : class
{
    public ContentSection([NotNull] TContent value, string path = ".")
    {
        Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        Path = path;
    }

    public TContent Value { get; }

    public string Path { get; }
}

public static class ContentSection
{
    // You use ?? to support the null-pattern in case there is no response.

    public static ContentSection<JToken> FromJToken(JToken content, string path = ".")
    {
        return new ContentSection<JToken>(content ?? JToken.Parse("{}"), path);
    }

    public static ContentSection<JValue> FromJValue(JValue content, string path = ".")
    {
        return new ContentSection<JValue>(content ?? JValue.CreateNull(), path);
    }
}

// This needs to be copy because it otherwise won't pass the middleware/assert "barrier"
// between the server and the "client".
public class RequestCopy
{
    public UriString Uri { get; set; }

    public HttpMethod Method { get; set; }

    public IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; set; }

    public long? ContentLength { get; set; }

    public Stream Content { get; set; }
}

public static class RequestCopyExtensions
{
    public static bool CanShortCircuit(this RequestCopy request) => !(request is null);

    // Deserializes the content of request-copy for further analysis.
    public static JToken DeserializeAsJToken(this RequestCopy request)
    {
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValue("Content-Type", out var contentType) && contentType != MimeType.Json)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"This method can deserialize only {MimeType.Json} content.");
        }

        if (request.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            return default;
        }

        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // You copy it because otherwise it'll get disposed when the request-copy vanishes.
            request.Content.Rewind().CopyTo(memory);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory.Rewind()))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JToken.Parse(body);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ResponseMock : IDisposable
{
    public ResponseMock(int statusCode, object content, string contentType)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Content = content;
        ContentType = contentType;
    }

    public int StatusCode { get; }

    [CanBeNull]
    public object Content { get; }

    public string ContentType { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        (Content as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### Json assertions

There is also a set of extensions that simplify content validation. I currently work only with `JSON` so only this kind of extensions exist. However, the `ContentSection<T>` is built to support other content-types if necessary.

```
public static class ContentAssert
{
    // Use this the same pattern for each assert: condition ? throw : content

    #region JToken helpers 

    [NotNull]
    public static ContentSection<JValue> Value(this ContentSection<JToken> content, string jsonPath)
    {
        return
            !(content.Value.SelectToken(jsonPath) is JValue value)
                ? throw DynamicException.Create("ContentPropertyNotFound", $"There is no such property as '{jsonPath}'")
                : ContentSection.FromJValue(value, jsonPath);
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static ContentSection<JToken> HasProperty(this ContentSection<JToken> content, string jsonPath)
    {
        return
            content.Value.SelectToken(jsonPath) is null
                ? throw DynamicException.Create("ContentPropertyNotFound", $"There is no such property as '{jsonPath}'")
                : content;
    }

    #endregion

    #region JValue helpers

    [NotNull]
    public static ContentSection<JValue> IsNotNull(this ContentSection<JValue> content)
    {
        return
            content.Value.Equals(JValue.CreateNull())
                ? throw DynamicException.Create("ValueNull", $"Value at '{content.Path}' is null.")
                : content;
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static ContentSection<JValue> IsEqual(this ContentSection<JValue> content, object expected)
    {
        return
            !content.Value.Equals(new JValue(expected))
                ? throw DynamicException.Create("ValueNotEqual", $"Value at '{content.Path}' is '{content.Value}' but should be '{expected}'.")
                : content;
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static ContentSection<JValue> IsLike(this ContentSection<JValue> content, [RegexPattern] string pattern, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    {
        return
            !Regex.IsMatch(content.Value.Value<string>() ?? string.Empty, pattern, options)
                ? throw DynamicException.Create("ValueNotLike", $"Value at '{content.Path}' is '{content.Value}' but should be like '{pattern}'.")
                : content;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

#### Extensibility

I build this framework as I use it and new assertion use-cases emerge with each project so I'd like it to be primarily extendible at this endpoint.

I currently can do the following:

- use different `URL` for each server.
- add other content-types because `ContentSection<T>` is extensible via `T` and consequently I can chain specific extension to it
- add other extensions to the `RequestBuilder` supporting more request assertions

#### Questions

Besides extensibilty I'd like this framework to be easy to use and intuitive. It should also provide useful feedback about what went wrong and where.

What is your rating?

---

*You can also take a look at it on [github](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/tree/dev/Reusable.Teapot/src).*

Comment: btw, I write _You_ in comments because I write to my future me ;-P

Comment: Should I expand any section and add more details?

Answer (score 1):

You allow a server to reuse an existing context when calling `BeginScope`. Does this mean multiple integration tests could reuse a context? If so, how do you handle disposal of the context? Your example shows one test that handles disposal of a possibly shared context.

> ```
> public ITeapotServerContext BeginScope()
> {
>      // CR: who should be allowed to handle the lifetime of a shared context?
>     return _serverContexts.GetOrAdd(Guid.NewGuid(), 
>         id => new TeapotServerContext(Disposable.Create(
>              () => _serverContexts.TryRemove(id, out _))));
> }
> ```

Maybe consumers of the API should not be able to dispose a context, but could register and unregister on a shared context. The server would then be responsible for lifetime management of each context. I would remove `IDisposable` from the interface definition of `ITeapotServerContext`.

> ```
> public void Dispose()
> {
>     // CR: what if context is shared?
>     _serverContext.Dispose();
>     _http.Dispose();
> }
> ```

---

The constructor of `TeapotServer` performs some configuration, followed by starting the host. I'm personally not a fan of doing anything more than storing state and configuring the instance in a constructor. Further initialisation - like IO operations - should be done in a method called `Initialise()`.

> ```
> _host.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
> ```

---

Talking about extensibility, I'm not sure whether `ITeapotServerContext` should be an interface. I don't see any other possible implementation besides the one you provided. Its lifetime and dispose pattern is also an internal occasion.

Comment: Contexts should be used on per-test basis. Since it is not possible to inject them via test-method parameters, there are only two possibilities, either create one in the constructor (it's called for each test) and dispose it after a test is run or with the `using` statement. I chose ctor as xunit handles this very nicely and reduces nesting. MSTest has the `TestInitialize` (=`.ctor`) and `TestCleanUp` (=`Dispose()`) attributes respectively. I also think I might have overused-interfaces here ;-]